# Thymeleaf nested condition in th:with

Tags: thymeleaf

I would like to do sommeting like that:

```
<div id="header_nav" th:fragment="header_nav (someId)" th:with="navPrefix=${'/content' + (someId ? ('/'+someId) : '')"}">
```

and use it later as *{navPrefix} within the div. I somehow don't get it with the condition nesting.
Can anyone help me?
Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is because you're using `th:include` when you use the fragment. According to the [Thymeleaf Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinclude-and-threplace) `th:include` simply includes the fragments content:

> Whereas th:include will include the contents of the fragment into its host tag, th:replace will actually substitute the host tag by the fragment’s

If you're using `th:include` then your `th:with` won't be getting included, so it will always be blank. You can observe this with other attributes in the same element as the `th:fragment` declaration, such as `style`.

You can get around this by using `th:replace` instead, which will swap the entire fragment, not just the contents. Or, you can wrap your fragment contents with a `th:block` which you can use to define `navPrefix`:

```
<div th:fragment="header_nav(someId)">
    <th:block th:with="navPrefix = ${'/content' + (someId != null ? ('/' + someId) : '')} ">
        ... contents of fragment ...
    </th:block>
</div>
```

Comment: That works a charm, cannot vote up though due to insufficient reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

The only issues I see are the extra double quotes at the end, and your ternary operator doesn't contain a boolean expression when you pass in a String.

The following works to display either the prefix or the passed parameter within the block:

```
<div id="header_nav" 
    th:fragment="header_nav(someId)" 
    th:with="navPrefix = ${'/content' + (someId != null ? ('/' + someId) : '')} ">

        <div th:text="${someId}"></div>
        <div th:text="${navPrefix}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this approach does not work for me. The 'someId' param is definitely passed to the fragmet's scope but the 'navPrefix' is not present.